# При умножении двух Dataframe, если nan оставить данные из первой таблицы

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Есть таблица с фактическими продажами по суткам

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame( {'Магазин': ['first','first','second','second','second'],
                     'Дата': ['01.01.2020','02.01.2020','01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020'],
                     'Товар1' : ['2','35','6','85','10'],
                     'Товар2': ['5','7','8','10','15'],
                     'Товар3' : ['25','235','46','855','100'],
})

df_1['Дата']=pd.to_datetime(df_1['Дата'])
df_1=df_1.set_index(['Магазин','Дата'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица с корректировкой:

```
df_corr = pd.DataFrame( {'Магазин': ['first','first','second','second','second'],
                     'Дата': ['01.01.2020','02.01.2020','01.01.2020','02.01.2020'],
                     'Товар1' : ['0.8','2','3','0.4'],

})

df_corr['Дата']=pd.to_datetime(df_corr['Дата'])
df_corr=df_corr.set_index(['Магазин','Дата'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне перемножить эти 2 таблицы, чтобы на выходе получить:

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame( {'Магазин': ['first','first','second','second','second'],
                     'Дата': ['01.01.2020','02.01.2020','01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020'],
                     'Товар1' : ['1.6','70','18','34','10'],
                     'Товар2': ['5','7','8','10','15'],
                     'Товар3' : ['25','235','46','855','100'],
})
```

[image: результат]

Т.е. перемножить значения в общих ячейках, а если значений во второй таблице нет, оставить первоначальные числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать простое произведение:

```
res = (df_1["Товар1"] * df_corr["Товар1"]).fillna(df_1["Товар1"])
df_1 = df_1.merge(res, how="right").set_index(df_1.index).fillna(df_1)
```

df_1:

```
                    Товар1 Товар2 Товар3
Магазин Дата                            
first   2020-01-01     1.6      5     25
        2020-02-01    70.0      7    235
second  2020-01-01    18.0      8     46
        2020-02-01    34.0     10    855
        2020-03-01    10.0     15    100
```

Только не забудьте сначала привести тип колонки "Товар1" в обоих фреймах к float:

```
df_corr["Товар1"] = df_corr["Товар1"].astype(float)
df_1["Товар1"] = df_1["Товар1"].astype(float)
```